# How to make a random number generator that prints out only 4 RANDOM NUMBERS at a time?

Tags: c

If I want to create a username generator in C? How do I go about it? I do understand that the question has been asked. But, I don't see anyone asking it in C language.
I think making it from a random word from the dictionary is going to be a little complicated for me to understand. I am right now only going to concentrate on a simple thing, and that is GENERATING 4 RANDOM NUMBERS. Now, before anyone says it's not secure or anything, this is purely for my curiosity and tinkering experience! I am enjoying learning C and I want to learn more.

The code that I have been able to come up with (minus the generator!) is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int randomnumbers; // this is for storing whatever random numbers I may   generate
char NAME[15];
prinf("What is your first name? \n");// 
scanf("%s \n", NAME);// I put it caps so that I can easily see it

printf("The username for %s is %s%d \n",NAME,NAME,randomnumbers);

return 0;
}
```

In case you find that the code is lacking and is of poor taste, I apologise. I am a newbie with less than a week in experience in coding. I thank you for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) is what you need.

```
int randomnumbers = rand();
```

You may also want to read on how to [seed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) the random number generator

Bonus random username generator:

```
// buffer must have memory for len + 1 elements
void generateUserName(/*out*/ char *buffer, int len)
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int idx = 0;
   while (idx < len) buffer[idx++] = rand() % 26 + 'a';
   buffer[len] = '\0';
}
```

To be called as

```
char userName[10];
generateUserName(userName, sizeof(userName) - 1);
printf("%s\n", userName);
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I suspect it's because while your answer isn't wrong, it's fairly incomplete; e.g. it doesn't show how to use a random *number* generator to produce a random string.

Comment: @Jules The OP doesn't asks so. 
Quoting from the question:
<quote> I am right now only going to concentrate on a simple thing, and that is generating 4 random numbers </quote>
To generate 4 random numbers all you  need is the rand function.

Comment: Fair point, I misread

Comment: @Jules Added the random username generator anyways. :sigh

Comment: @bashrc thanks! :D